# Boost IPC: Only remove shared object when the last process is closed

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, boost-interprocess

I'm currently using Boost's shared memory for IPC. 
I only want to remove the shared memory when the last process exits. If I try to remove the object before the last process, it will change the name and it's then not possible to reopen it for another process.

One solution I thought of is to store a ref-counter within the shared memory and increment it every time the shared memory is opened (and decrement on close). However, if a process would terminate, the counter might not then decrement. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Are the processes all spawned from one place? If so, that parent process would know about the uses of the shared resource and could manage it for the children?

Comment: @Joe unfortunately not. The shared memory will be used in X (as in no defined amount) separated apps and they'll be started manually by the user.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to be platform agnostic?

Comment: @Joe That is a correct assumption!

Comment: There was a discussion about similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31711443/4899330)

Comment: I was gonna mention interprocess::shared_ptr, but the @doqtor already linked it :)